# Printing a two dimensional list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a two dimensional list to represent a console game of connect four. It should look like this:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .
 .  .  R  .  .  .  .
 .  .  Y  R  .  .  .
 .  R  R  Y  .  Y  .
```

This is what I have so far, and I can't seem to get it to work, I keep getting a "IndexError" saying "tuple index out of range".
Keep in mind, in the module connect_four, BOARD_ROWS is equal to 6 and BOARD_COLUMNS is 7.
NONE is ' ', RED is 'R', and YELLOW is 'Y'. Also, the game_state is a namedtuple object with two fields, which the first off, is the game board (list of strings).

```
def print_board(game_state) -> None:
    """ Prints the game board given the current game state """
    print("1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
    for a in range(connect_four.BOARD_ROWS):
        for b in range(connect_four.BOARD_COLUMNS):
            if game_state[b][a] == connect_four.NONE:
                print('.', end=' ')
            elif game_state[b][a] == connect_four.RED:
                print('R', end=' ')
            elif game_state[b][a] == connect_four.YELLOW:
               print('Y', end=' ')
            else:
               print('\n', end='')
```

Code for Namedtuple

```
def _new_game_board() -> [[str]]:
    """
    Creates a new game board.  Initially, a game board has the size
    BOARD_COLUMNS x BOARD_ROWS and is comprised only of strings with the
    value NONE
    """
    board = []

    for col in range(BOARD_COLUMNS):
        board.append([])
        for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
            board[-1].append(NONE)

    return board

ConnectFourGameState = collections.namedtuple('ConnectFourGameState', ['board', 'turn'])


def new_game_state() -> ConnectFourGameState:
    """
    Returns a ConnectFourGameState representing a brand new game
    in which no moves have been made yet.
    """
    return ConnectFourGameState(board=_new_game_board(), turn=RED)
```

Comment: Why not use `for a in range(len(game_state))` and `for b in range(len(game_state[a]))`.

Comment: "Also, the game_state is a namedtuple object with two fields, which the first off, is the game board (list of strings)." Wait, so shouldn't you be doing `game_state.board[b][a]` instead of `game_state[b][a]` ?

Comment: Could you also share the code for your namedtuple?

Comment: You are correct about the .board part, thanks! As for the "(len(game_state)) and for b in range(len(game_state[a]))", I'm not so sure what is going on there.

Comment: Code for namedtuple has been added to original post

Comment: Instead of using the `if-else` make a look-up table (dictionary) that has the values of `.,R,Y` and look up with keys of game_state.board[row][col] ... and print that value...?

Comment: I'm not too sure how that accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you added the rest of the code, I'm slightly confused by your way of representing rows and columns so here is how I would write the code (if I was approaching the problem like you did); hope it helps:

```
def _new_game_board() -> [[str]]:
    """
    Creates a new game board.  Initially, a game board has the size
    BOARD_COLUMNS x BOARD_ROWS and is comprised only of strings with the
    value NONE
    """

    return [[None] * BOARD_COLUMNS for _ in range(BOARD_ROWS)]

ConnectFourGameState = namedtuple('ConnectFourGameState', ['board', 'turn'])

def new_game_state() -> ConnectFourGameState:
    """
    Returns a ConnectFourGameState representing a brand new game
    in which no moves have been made yet.
    """

    return ConnectFourGameState(board=_new_game_board(), turn=RED)
```

And as for the `print_board` function:

```
def print_board(game_state):
    """Prints the game board given the current game state"""

    print("1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
    for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
        for col in range(BOARD_COLUMNS):
            if game_state.board[row][col] == connect_four.NONE:
                print('.', end=' ')
            elif game_state.board[row][col] == connect_four.RED:
                print('R', end=' ')
            elif game_state.board[row][col] == connect_four.YELLOW:
               print('Y', end=' ')

        print()
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about that because I get this as output:

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
. . . . . .       and then it just end there is an error

Comment: Could you also share the code for your `namedtuple`?

Comment: Code for namedtuple has been added to original post

Comment: I think the misconnection occurred because my _new_game_board returns a list with 7 sublists, each comprised of 6 empty items. However, yours returns a big list of 6 sublists, each of 7 empty items.
At any rate, thanks, this solved my issue. I would upvote your answer but I need a reputation of at least 15.

Comment: Glad it helped! I think your reputation is more than 15 now :-)